# ¿como poner una ventana sobre cualquier otra aunque este en pantalla completa?

Tags: c++, qt, gtk

¿Es posible poner una ventana o elemento que se superponga a cualquier otra cosa que este abierta? en gtk o qt. (c++ en linux)

Lo mas parecido a la marca de agua de windows 10

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tal vez lo soluciones usando el flag Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint .Mira el enlace: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-windowflags-example.html

Comment: @user3733164 voy a probarlo, creo que podría servirme. Solo tengo que hacer la ventana transparente como el terminal de linux y quitar el borde.

Comment: Por defecto en **Qt** cuando abres una ventana de la app que haces y tienes otra ventana abierta de la misma app, la nueva se superpone sobre la que está, puedes usar un **showmodal** para evitar operar sobre las otras ventanas mientras tienes abierta una. Otra forma de hacer lo que quieres es usando `QDockWidget` para que puedas tener ventanas separadas de otras y al mismo tiempo si lo deseas puedes empotrarlas en una ventana en específico.